# Elements in layout cropped

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a problem with layout file, when i test it on devices with Android 4.1, why does it happens I don't know, so here's what i get:

[image]

And here's the part of layout where it happens:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/chooseType"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox2" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox3" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkboxHomes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_checkboxhouses" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkboxRooms"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_checkboxrooms" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

I've tried to remove layout weight but it seems that somehow LinearLayout ignores it and tries to crop the last element in layout.

Comment: Are you using 9 patches? Maybe there's too much padding in them.

Comment: @DerGolem no, I'm not using 9 patches, just simple pngs.

Comment: OK, maybe there's too much transparent borders in them.

Comment: @DerGolem nope, if it was the problem it appeared on all of the devices, but this problem appears only on 4.1 Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you use `LinearLayout`'s weights, children which you set weight should have 
`android:layout_width="0dp"` (or `android:layout_width` when `LinearLayout`'s orientation is vertical).

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) you have an explanation.

Second case is that you did not set weight to last of checkboxes :)

Comment: Yeah, i noticed that the last elements have no weight :) But thx anyway, i'll accept your answer and give you a plus :)

Comment: How could I miss that! +1